Can you please explain and give me real-life examples of using the following grammar?
In Advanced Grammar in Use, it's said that 'When the future event doesn't depend on the action described in if-clause, we use be going to not will. This kind of sentence is mainly found in spoken English.'. The examples given are:
I'm going to open the bottle of lemonade if you want some.
I'll open a bottle of lemonade if you want some.
I understand them but when I searched for others, I found some unambiguous ones such as:
If you check your phone, you're going to see notifications. (Here, it seems that seeing notifications depends on checking the phone)
If you go outside, you're going to be wet. (Getting wet seems to depend on the action of going outside)

The speaker means "I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade [for myself, so you can have some] if you want some". They're going to open it anyway, whether the other person wants some or not. It doesn't mean that all 'if' sentences containing 'be going to' have to fit that pattern.

How about "If you check your phone, you’re going to see notifications."? I think if I don't look at the phone, I won't know there're some notifications. So the action in the main clause depends on the action in the if-clause.

Yes, it does. As I said, not all sentences containing 'if' and 'going to' fit the pattern of your first example.

So the meaning is the same as when using "will", I'm a bit confused.

The point is that in a sentence like the lemonade one, when 'if' implies an offer to share  rather than a condition for opening the bottle, we use 'going to' - but in other kinds of 'if' sentences we can use either 'going to' or 'will'.

will or going to depends on what you actually want to mean. In your examples, it is the difference between an action and sharing what you're offering with the person.

You often hear this pattern used when someone is offering something. For example:

I'm going to be running errands if you need anything.

This means that the speaker is running errands (probably going to a grocery store, maybe going to the post office or a bank) anyway. And is inviting the listener to request any errands they need the speaker to do.
You can best understand this by separating the two phrases. One complete thought is "I'm going to be running errands" and there is a second thought of "If you need anything, [please ask]."
Another example is:

I'm going to ride my bike if you want to come.

This is similar, they are two separate phrases being said as one. "I'm going to ride my bike." and "If you want to come, [you can]."

Further to this answer, in such uses of the construct “P if Q,” the meaning is along the lines of “P, just so you know. And because P, should it be the case that Q, then [some (usually only implied) context-specific conclusion].”

The offering something is with will, not going to. You don't make the will/going to distinction.

"if" is irrelevant here:

I'll open a bottle of champagne [if you want one].
I'm going to open a bottle of champagne [if you want one].

The difference is not in the if clause, it's in the meaning of the main clause. The first one is an offer to do something, the second is a statement.

I'll open the window to let in some fresh air.

I'll open a bottle of lemonade if you want some.


That usage is when you offer to do something for someone. In question form in the first person, it becomes: Shall I open a bottle of lemonade for you? In these cases, it would not be: Will I etc.
going to + infinitive is "some definite action or situation".

I'm going open a bottle of lemonade. [a definite action that will occur]


Cambridge Dictionary:
Willingness and offers
Will is often used to express someone’s willingness to do something or to make offers. It is often used with I in this context:
I’ll show you where to go.
A: It’s just a leaflet that I’ve got.
B: Just the leaflet. Right, I’ll go and get you a brochure too.
I’ll give you a lift to the hotel.
Cambridge Dictionary

Related usage:
And finally, with shall (I or we), the answer is let's x.

Shall I open the window for you? Yes, please do.
Shall we leave early so we can get there on time? Yes, let's [leave early].
Shall we go? Yes, let's [go].

These  uses do not depend on the if clause. The depend on how will/going to work in context.
